# Selenium not allowing any form data control on GitHub Website

Tags: python, github, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently using Selenium to create a browser and run some automation.  Currently, I'm able to log-in to GitHub, click settings tabs, profile tabs, etc.

However, my problem comes when I want to work with one of the pages in particular which is a Webhook.

I open the Webhook page with Selenium, however, none of the automation works after that.  I've tried entering data into a field, clicking a drop down list, clicking a radio-button etc and nothing seems to work.  I'm wondering if I'm reading the HTML wrong or the code is incorrect etc.

```
<input placeholder="https://example.com/postreceive" class="form-control js-hook-url-field" autocomplete="off" type="url" name="hook[url]" id="hook_url">
```

Python:

```
web_hook_link = repository_url + '/settings/hooks/new'
driver.get(web_hook_link)


## This should enter data into the url field but doesn't.
## tried implementing the driver.find(element).click() as well but no luck
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=1200).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "hook_url")) 
driver.find_element((By.ID,"hook_url")).send_keys(web_hook_discord_full)

## This should do the selector for the drop down but doesnt
selector = Select(driver.find_element((By.ID, "hook_content_type")))
selector.select_by_value("json")

## This should click a radio button but doesn't
driver.find_element((By.ID, "hook-event-choice-everything")).click()
```

I've tried using all sorts of types i.e. `By.NAME`, `By.XPATH`, and copying their respective values but no luck.

Am I reading the HTML wrong, is there a limitation to Selenium, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out.  It looks like all the doubled parenthesis were causing issues.

For example:

`driver.find_element((By.ID, "hook-event-choice-everything")).click()`

was changed to:

`driver.find_element(By.ID, "hook-event-choice-everything").click()`

and now everything is working as intended.